# How to fix error "The system cannot find the file specified." when trying to access a Firebird database

Tags: python, json, firebird, firebird2.5

My approach so far has been very straightforward but I'm struggling to get the fdb file parsed and connected.

I downloaded the correct version of Firebird (2.5) for the file I have. I attempted to do this

```py
con = fdb.connect(dsn='202204.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
```

This results in the following error:

> 202204.FDB.delta"\n- Error while trying to open file\n- The system cannot find the file specified. ', -902, 335544344)

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing this delta file? Is there a better approach for this?

Note: I have no experience working with Firebird.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the .delta in the error message. This means that you have been given a copy of a Firebird database in backup-mode. In general, that is a bad idea, using a gbak backup to transfer files is better. You will need to fixup the database to end the backup mode without having a delta file. I'll post an answer later when I have time to try the exact steps to do that.

Comment: I believe using `nbackup -F 202204.fdb` (using the nbackup tool of your Firebird install) should do this, you should then be able to connect. See also [Restoring a backup made after “nbackup -L”](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html#nbackup-restore-and-fixup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the database file you have was copied while the database was in backup-mode (or "stalled"). In this mode, the main database file is not updated and updates are written into a delta file. This mode is entered when the command `ALTER DATABASE BEGIN BACKUP` is executed (or the `nbackup -lock <database>` command).

In a normal situation, this delta file is reintegrated into the database once the `ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP` is executed (or the `nbackup -n <database>` command, or - Firebird 3.0 and higher - `nbackup -unlock <database>`).

However, in your case, you only have a copy of the stalled database. To be able to use the database, you need to "fixup" the database with the command `nbackup -f <database>`. `nbackup` is a commandline tool included in the Firebird installation directory (in Firebird 2.5, in the `bin` directory of the Firebird installation). After the fixup, the database will be identical to how it was *before* the backup mode was entered, any changes after that are **lost** in your copy.

**Warning**: Only perform the fixup if this is actually just a copy, otherwise you should really obtain the delta file, and use `ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP` or `nbackup -n <database>` to avoid loss of data. Once a database is "fixed up", it is not possible to reintegrate a delta file.

See also the [Firebird nbackup tool documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html), specifically the chapter [Locking and unlocking](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html#nbackup-lock-unlock).